# How to evaluate Accuracy for Classification model in Pyspark?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, classification, apache-spark-mllib, multiclass-classification

I am working on pyspark and running model on multi-class classification problem but don't know how to evaluate accuracy of classification model.

This is my code for logistic regression it is also computing time for model.

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression    
log_reg = LogisticRegression(featuresCol='features',labelCol='Accident_Severity')   
start = time.perf_counter()    
log_reg.fit(train)    
end = time.perf_counter()    
duration = format((end-start),'.4f')
print("Logistic Regression Time in Seconds :", duration)
```

[Here is a screenshot with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb66K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` as described [here in the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.html)